# Move converted file after each encode and delete original file on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, automation

I encode in batch and would like it to move the converted file to another directory after completing each encode and delete the original file.

Here is my current bash I use to convert using FFMPEG.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mkv;
do 
#Output new files by prepending "X265" to the names  
ffmpeg -threads 32 -i "$i" \
   -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le \
   -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k \
   -c:s copy \
   -map 0:0 \
   -map 0:1 \
   -map 0:2 \
   -x265-params "bframes=6:no-sao:frame-threads=3:numa-pools:8:slices=5:interlace=0:ref=6:rd=1:rect:analysis-reuse-mode:analysis-reuse-level=10:refine-mv:me=2:merange=64:rc-lookahead=60:b-adapt=2" \
   -max_muxing_queue_size 4000 X265_"$i"
done
```

Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
for i in *.mkv;
do 
    # your ffmpeg command...
    mv X265_"$i" <target folder>
    rm -f -- "$i"
done
```

Comment: Will the rm -f -- "$i" delete all files in folder or just the converted?

Comment: just converted.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much I had been messing with it and it kept deleting the entire folder so this helps!

Comment: you're welcome. you can accept my answer if it is what you want